Understanding the step of quotienting the disjoint union in construction of CW complexes
I am reading Hatcher and trying to understand how CW complexes are to be constructed. I find the construction incredibly confusing...

(see page $5$ of Hatcher's Algebraic Topology):
(1) Start with a discrete set $X^0$ , whose points are regarded as $0$ cells.
(2) Inductively, form the $n$ skeleton $X^n$ from $X^{n−1}$ by attaching $n$ cells $e_{\alpha}^n$ via maps $\phi_{\alpha}:S^{n-1} \to X^{n-1}$. This means that $X^n$ is the quotient space of the disjoint union $X^{n−1} \sqcup_{\alpha} D_{\alpha}^n$ of $X^{n−1}$ with a collection of $n$ disks $D_{\alpha}^n$ under the identifications $x \sim \phi_{\alpha}(x)$ for $x \in \partial
(D_{\alpha}^n)$. Thus as a set $X^n=X^{n-1}\sqcup_{\alpha} e^n_\alpha,$ where $e^n_\alpha$ is an open $n-$ disk.
A space $X$ constructed in this way is called a cell complex or CW complex.
Understanding CW complex construction

To introduce the problem I have, let me try construct a circle through the above schema

We start some space of discrete points $X^0 = \{0\}$

Now, for one cell, we add a single interval and we can get a circle by gluing both ends to the 0 cell.

We define $X^1 = X^0\sqcup_{\alpha} D_{\alpha}^1 =   X^0\sqcup I =\{ (0,a) , \{(i,b) | i \in I\} \}$. Note that I introduce the second slot expression to emphasize that it's disjoint union. After this, it is said to glue by some maps  $\phi : S^0 \to X^0$. The confusion starts exactly at this point.

But, let's leave that aside... how can we quotient a set by a relation which is defined through elements not in that set? For instance, we say that $x ~ \phi(x)$, but $x \in X^0$ and is not something which exists in the disjoint union (perhaps we quotient the embedding of $S^{n-1}$ in the disjoint union)
Even ignoring the tags how does $\phi$ evaluate on the $X^{n-1}$ part of the disjoint union
Note: $S^0$ is a pair of poitns as rightly pointed out by a user in the comments.

Of course, $x$ belongs to the $\alpha$th component of the right side of the disjoint union while $\phi_\alpha(x)$ belongs to the left side of the disjoint union. The tags are left implicit. (Also, did you mean $X^0 = {0}$?)

Just a side note: if you care about formal definitions (which is a good thing if you do), you should try looking for a different book. Hatcher's style is extremely non rigorous.

Also, $S^0$ is the discrete space on two points, not one. (It is the set of points of $\mathbb{R}$ with distance $1$ from the origin, or the suspension of the empty space, or the boundary of the interval.)

Ah I see. That's interesting cause D^0 is just a single point @NaïmFavier

The sphere should be the boundary of the disk, and the boundary of $[-1,1]$ consists of two points.

You should write an answer. I understood it from you first comment now I read it again

To start with, your set theoretic expression for $X^0 \sqcup I$ is wrong. It should instead be
$$\underbrace{\{(0,a)\}}_{X^0 \times \{a\}} \cup \underbrace{\{(i,b) \mid i \in I \}}_{I \times \{b\}}
$$
If you insist on squishing that all of that into one single pair of set braces, perhaps you can write it as
$$\{(0,a), (i,b) \mid i \in I\}
$$
But now let me make a suggestion: don't use $a$ and $b$. Instead use $0$ and $1$. Also, be explicit about $I=[0,1]$. Now you can visualize the set as a subset of $\mathbb R^2$:
$$\{(0,0)\} \cup \{(t,1) \mid 0 \le t \le 1\}
$$
Now perhaps you can see that you are are quotienting that set by an equivalence relation that is defined on elements of that set. There is one equivalence class with three points, namely
$$\{(0,0),(0,1),(1,1)\}
$$
Every other equivalence class has a single point, and these classes are
$$\{(t,1)\} \qquad 0 < t < 1
$$

I see that you want to replace the tags $a,b$ with $0,1$ to produce a good visualization of the diisjoint union. On the other hand, this replacement gives $0$ and $1$ more roles than they already had (dimensions and endpoints of $I$) and that might confuse some people (even if not the OP) when writing things down in detail. I'd be inclined to use tage $3,7$, avoiding overloading and (perhaps) emphasizing that the choice of tags is arbitrary (So arbitrary that Hatcher apparently ignores the tags altogether).

What I quite like about that choice of tags is the easily proved fact that $X^0 \cup I$ is actually homeomorphic to that subset of $\mathbb R^2$. So one obtains the CW complex as a quotient of a very concrete mathematical object. Nothing's wrong with that.

In my experience, one common downfall of students' understanding of topology is their failure to appreciate how much of it can be done very concretely, based on ordinary analytic geometry.

In my experience, students struggle with the exact opposite: understanding that most mathematics can be done structurally, without regard for the actual set-theoretic encoding of the objects involved. To that end I'd be inclined to choose tags like $\text{left}$ and $\text{right}$, simply assuming that there exists a two-element set ${\text{left}, \text{right}}$.
